# How can I dynamically add a textbox to the part of text i click edit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynamic

I'm creating a webpage. My Accounts page is more or less like the "Facebook's" account page.

My page's image: http://tinypic.com/r/2e51t2t/5

In this page I want to add a textbox dynamically to the part of the text i click edit.
I know I can achieve the same by going to a new page, but I want to do it dynamically in the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the textbox disabled or readonly then use JQuery to enable it triggering the click(edit) event. You can try something like this.

```
<input type='text' name='username' id='user' readonly> <a href='#' id='edit_user'>Edit</a>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
         $('#edit_user').click(function()
         {
             $('#user').removeProp('readonly');
         });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: actually i'm new to jquery. Can you please post the jquery code to achieve it.

Comment: @SouravmoyGorai can you accept my answer for this question to be closed. tnx. just click the check button beside my answer.